# MySQL - search records from table B which lie within multiple time ranges from table A

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, select

MySQL version = 5.7.29
This is my table A:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║StartDate           ║EndDate             ║Var          ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║2020-06-19 00:00:00 ║2020-06-19 00:20:00 ║b            ║
║2020-06-19 00:20:01 ║2020-06-19 00:40:00 ║a            ║
║2020-06-19 00:40:01 ║2020-06-19 01:00:00 ║a            ║
║2020-06-19 01:00:01 ║2020-06-19 01:20:00 ║b            ║  
║2020-06-19 01:20:01 ║2020-06-19 01:40:00 ║a            ║
║2020-06-19 01:40:01 ║2020-06-19 02:00:00 ║b            ║
║2020-06-19 02:00:01 ║2020-06-19 02:20:00 ║a            ║
║2020-06-19 02:20:01 ║2020-06-19 02:40:00 ║b            ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

This is my table B:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║cDate               ║Val1                ║Val2         ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║2020-06-19 00:01:00 ║102                 ║a1           ║
║2020-06-19 00:25:21 ║05                  ║a2           ║
║2020-06-19 00:49:01 ║94                  ║b3           ║
║2020-06-19 01:10:01 ║04                  ║b23          ║  
║2020-06-19 01:15:04 ║10                  ║1            ║
║2020-06-19 01:28:01 ║56                  ║2            ║
║2020-06-19 02:00:09 ║29                  ║3            ║
║2020-06-19 02:38:01 ║24                  ║4            ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want all the rows from table B where cDate lies between StartDate,EndDate from table A where var = 'a'

Lets say if there was only 1 timestamp per Var in table A:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║StartDate           ║EndDate             ║Var          ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║2020-06-19 00:00:00 ║2020-06-19 00:20:00 ║b            ║
║2020-06-19 00:20:01 ║2020-06-19 00:40:00 ║a            ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The following query would have worked

```
select * from tableB where Cdate >= (select startDate from tableA where var = 'a') and cDate <= (select EndDate from tableA where var = 'b')
```

But in the current case where there are multiple timestamps per Var, how can I do this?

Comment: Start with a proper JOIN, instead of using subselects.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the 2 tables on your conditions:

```
select distinct b.cDate, b.Val1, b.Val2
from b inner join a
on b.cDate between a.StartDate and a.EndDate and a.Var = 'a'
```

or with `EXISTS`:

```
select b.* from b
where exists (
  select 1 from a 
  where b.cDate between a.StartDate and a.EndDate and a.Var = 'a'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select b.*
from tableb b
where exists (
    select 1 from tablea 
    where b.cDate >= a.startDate and b.cDate < a.endDate
)
```

You might need to adjust the inequalities to your exact requirement - I used half-open intervals (`>=` on the low value and `<` on the high value).